# Display the date of creation of a row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I added a new row to my users' table to show the date of creation of each user.
I tried both timestamp and datetime types for that but it still displays me 0000-00-00 00:00:00 next to each user.

here's my code for adding the rows to the users's table

```
$first_name = trim($_REQUEST['first_name']);
$last_name = trim($_REQUEST['last_name']);
$username = trim($_REQUEST['username']);
$password = trim($_REQUEST['password']);
$email = trim($_REQUEST['email']);
$created = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time());
$insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, password, email, created)" .
"VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');",
mysql_real_escape_string($first_name),
mysql_real_escape_string($last_name),
mysql_real_escape_string($username),
mysql_real_escape_string(crypt($password, $username)),
mysql_real_escape_string($email),
mysql_real_escape_string($created));
mysql_query($insert_sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

And here's the code that displays the informations

```
$select_users = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result =  mysql_query($select_users);
while ($user = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$user_row = sprintf(
"<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox[]' value='%d'/></td>" .
"<td>%s %s</td> " .
"<td>%s</td>" .
"<td><a href='mailto:%s'>%s</a></td> " .
"<td>%s</td>" .
"<td><a href='javascript:delete_user(%d);'><img class='delete_user' src='images/trash.png' alt='' title='' border='0' /></a></td>",
$user['user_id'], $user['first_name'], $user['last_name'], $user[username],
$user['email'], $user['email'], $user['created'], $user['user_id']);
echo $user_row;
```

I got all the fields displayed correctly except for the creation date which shows 0000-00-00 00:00:00 .
I don't know what I did wrong.
Thank you for the help.

EDIT : I already have a field called "updated" which uses "Current_timestamp".

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Okay, I'll keep in mind your suggestion, It's just that I'm new to php.

Comment: All the better reason to learn PDO or MySQLi ;)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the time with php, you could make a field in the database named created with type of timestamp and set default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. This will automaticly do what you need without php.
Here is the code:

```
    ALTER TABLE `users` ADD COLUMN `created` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has the possibility to have a timestamp on a field that is inserted when the record is created.

In your SQL put this for the created:

```
`Created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

You do not need any PHP code to handle the timestamp.

Comment: I kow that but I already have a field called "updated" for future updates. So I did this to keep the original date of creation. And CURRENT_TIMESTAMP can only be used once.

Comment: That is true. When I need to update a timestamp with PHP I use date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );

Comment: @peterburg Hang on; 'updated' uses current_timestamp as a default?

Comment: Yes !that's why I can't use current_timestamp with created .

Comment: That's probably something you should add to your question @peterburg, since half of the answers so far involve altering your table

Answer (score 0):

try
    $created = date("m-d-y H:i:s", time());

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add the current time within MySQL without reusing current_timestamp. Try this as your insertion query; it doesn't involve any database schema changes, and it should still get you the correct result:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, password, email, created)"
. "VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', now())"
```

Answer (score 0):

A potential workaround is that since you know the value of $created, you don't really need to escape it. Therefore, your $insert_sql would be:

```
$insert_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, username, password, email, created)"
. "VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '".$created."');",
mysql_real_escape_string($first_name),
mysql_real_escape_string($last_name),
mysql_real_escape_string($username),
mysql_real_escape_string(crypt($password, $username)),
mysql_real_escape_string($email));
```

Note that this is ONLY ONLY ONLY when you absolutely control everything about the variable.

Comment: I try it but I still get these annoying zeros. I really don't understand what is going on. NOTE : the "updated" field has type "TIMESTAMP", default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", attributs="on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" ;and the "created" field has type="datetime", default="none" and not null.This is frustrating!

Comment: Just...as a check, is there zeroes in the database table itself? Like, can you access it through phpMyAdmin or mysql-workbench and check, @peterburg?

Comment: Also, did using now() in place of the datetime work (my previous answer)?

Comment: Yes; there's zeros in phpmyadmin. I tried now() also, and it didn't work .i don't know if it's an error in the sprintf expression which I doubt.

Comment: Hrm. I mean, try echoing $insert_sql. I just verified that now() correctly inserts into a datetime. Can you run `echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "\n";` after your mysql_query?

Comment: $link refers to what?! I noticed that even when I set the default value of 'created' to 'none' phpmyadmin shows "0000-00-00 00:00:00"!this is when I put the type of 'created' as 'timestamp' .

Comment: Whoops, $link isn't needed. I had copied and pasted from the PHP doc example. `echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";`